# Hashicorp Vault - Template Policy issues with UI

Tags: policy, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to establish a shared secret environment for all users but each user cannot see each others secrets. It is working as expected through the CLI but when I try to test it on the web UI it's stating that the test user does not have the correct permissions. I followed this guide https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/policy-templating and https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies.html for references but no matter what I do it is not working correctly on the web UI.

Here is how my policies look like.

```
path "secret/data/{{identity.entity.name}}/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "update", "read", "delete", "sudo"]
}
path "secret/metadata/{{identity.entity.name}}/*" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read", "create", "update", "delete", "sudo"]
}
```

CLI output:

```
$ vault kv list secret/user
Keys
----
test
```

UI output:
[image]

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can create a storage engine with the name of each user and give them access via the template policy.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
path "secret/data/{{identity.entity.name}}/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "update", "read", "delete", "sudo"]
}
path "secret/metadata/{{identity.entity.name}}/*" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}
path "secret/metadata" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}
```

The problem is that with your policy you have no access to the folder "secret" but only to the path "secret/data/{{identity.entity.name}}". In the navigation of the UI you need additional access rights for the parent folders.

Comment: This does show the path but each user can now see each other's path. So now user "Bob" can see user "Josh" if this policy was enforced and I did not want this behavior. I wanted to completely isolate each users path, not even allowing users to see each the others path. But thanks for the input, I'll keep testing this out.

Comment: With this setting the user only can see their own path and no other path. Im running exactly this setting. Try this out :)

Comment: It's amusing that this is conspiciously missing from the official documentation.